# Why does this macro invocation result in an unresolved name?

Tags: macros, rust

Here is a simplified version of a macro I am trying to implement for an RPC library I am working on:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! msgpack_rpc {
    (
        $(
            rpc $name:ident ( $( $arg:ident : $arg_ty:ty ),* ) -> $ret_ty:ty | $err_ty:ty;
        )+
    ) => (
        pub trait Service {
            $(
                fn $name ( &self, $( $arg : $arg_ty ),* ) -> Result<$ret_ty, $err_ty>;
            )+
        }

        pub struct Server;

        impl Server {
            pub fn listen<S>(handle: &(), address: (), service: S)
                    -> ::std::io::Result<()>
                    where S: Service + Send + Sync + 'static {
                let service = move |msg: &str| {
                    let result = match msg {
                        $(
                            stringify!($name) => {
                                service.$name($( $arg ),*)
                                    .map(String::from)
                                    .map_err(String::from)
                            }
                        ),+,
                        _ => String::from("method not supported".into()),
                    };
                };

                Ok(())
            }
        }
    )
}

msgpack_rpc! {
    rpc echo(arg: i64) -> i64 | ();
}
```

The macro expansion fails to compile with this error:

```
error: unresolved name `arg` [--explain E0425]
  --> <anon>:40:17
   |>
40 |>     rpc echo(arg: i64) -> i64 | ();
   |>                 ^
<anon>:39:1: 41:2: note: in this expansion of msgpack_rpc! (defined in <anon>)
```

From reading similar questions, I know that `macro_rules` sometimes has problems expanding statements. However, I am confused as to why it is having trouble expanding items in this case.

Is there a workaround to fix the expansion?

Comment: Have you tried supplying the `Service` and `Server` names as macro parameters?

Comment: No, I'd like the macro to just declare the items inline, with the expectation that the user expands inside a module if namespacing is desired.

Comment: Note that creating a [MCVE] is drastically useful in this type of situation; it's a skill that all good programmers should have. Here's [one potential MCVE for this case](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=79165c85749c3707b1149a5bd12862ec). Once you've produced a MCVE, the problem will usually become much more obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any variable named `arg` in the context in which you call the function. This is the "unresolved `arg`" the compiler is complaining about.

```
stringify!($name) => {
    $( let $arg = Default::default(); )*
    service.$name($( $arg ),*)
        .map(String::from)
        .map_err(String::from)
}
```